# FTP script Windows invalid command character appended?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, ftp

I am trying to figure out what is wrong in my script. I am trying to automate the task of getting data from many FTP servers, using PowerShell as scripting environment.

I am using

```
ftp.exe -n -s:Script.txt $SOMEIp
```

It was giving me output:

```
Connected to 10.128.10.195.
220 Service ready
User(10.128.10.195:(none)):
530 Invalid user
Login failed.
```

I tried some troubleshooting by experiencing with the script and so on - the initial result is that [image: FTP Error]

Is the "rectangle" char appending "a" character causing this or what is exactly wrong with the script?

In any case:

```
admin
password
cd ...
ascii
get somefile.txt
quit
```

is the script, while command to execute it, as I mentioned,

```
ftp.exe -n -s:Script.txt $SOMEIp
```

On the PNG file you see some troubleshooting file, where I tried to "ignore" the first wrong line and then restart with user and password prompt.

Would be great if you could share some ideas on that matter.

Cheers

Alex

Comment: What does it say for "Encoding" on the "Save As" dialog in Notepad? Try saving your script as ANSI, and see if that helps. Just an idea.

Comment: Great! It turned out to be the issue. The file was being saved as unicode. I changed it to ANSI and it kicked off :) Can you please post an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving your Script.txt as ASCII or ANSI. It could be that your ftp client doesn't understand unicode.

Comment: As stated, marking as an answer. Possibly a troubleshooting for future generations of scripting newbies like me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script to this:

```
user admin password
cd ..
ascii
get somefile.txt
quit
```

You need to tell the FTP server that what is coming is the username and password. Also, you need two dots not three to go up a level.

Comment: Why the downvote please? If you are going to downvote, please have the decency to explain why, so we can all learn.

Comment: I also dont know why would someone dvote that. I will check both suggestions when Ill have access to the remote system on Monday. As for the dots in CD, I meant dots as some random action :-) thanks for effort

Comment: FTP servers take a plain `username` and `password` on separate lines.

Comment: @foxidrive: FTP servers also take a command of the form "USER username password" all on one line. Here is my Mac, for example: ftp -n localhost
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
220 ::1 FTP server (tnftpd 20100324+GSSAPI) ready.
ftp> user mark freddyfrog
331 User mark accepted, provide password.
230 User mark logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.

Comment: @foxidrive: Here is the same on Ubuntu... http://askubuntu.com/questions/61429/how-do-i-execute-ftp-commands-on-one-line

Comment: @foxidrive: And here on superuser... http://superuser.com/questions/323214/how-to-upload-one-file-by-ftp-from-command-line

Comment: The FTP servers I have used don't accept a `user` field or username and password on one line.  I tested two extra servers before replying.  This is Windows FTP we are discussing too.

Comment: The OP doesn't say if his servers are Windows or not - only his client.

Comment: @foxidrive
To clarify - the target system is using some sort of embedded OS with ftp and http support. (http://www.doms.com/product_19.aspx).

Thanks again for support, I have learned my bit about that :-)

Comment: The TAGS are Windows cmd batch files and Windows Powershell. For anyone to assume it's not FTP.EXE under Windows without information to the contrary is impossibubble. :)  Notepad is also showing on the screen.  @MarkSetchell

Comment: @foxidrive : Like I said and you agree, the client is clearly Windows FTP.EXE which matches the TAGS. However, my point was that the server is not necesarily Windows (and the OP has confirmed that the server is not Windows in his comment above) and that Ubuntu/Linux and Mac OSX servers all accept different commands such as the "user username password" command I suggested in my original answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Oh, I see what you are saying. My understanding is that the FTP client is parsing the username/password string and that FTP server OS is immaterial.  I assumed the servers I was connecting to were Linux based.  If the FTP server login was not standard then the Windows FTP client scripts would break when another format was required.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I've confirmed that the FTP client translates the format of the username and password strings into what must be a standard FTP format login.  I used telnet to log into a *nix FTP server and the login format is a standard `USER username` and `PASS password` on separate command lines.  Hence your advice is for a MAC client and not Windows FTP.EXE client.